# how to apply filter inside directive

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive:

```
(function () {
    angular.module('app.components')
        .directive('myDirective', myDirective);

    myDirective.$inject = ['$http', '$timeout'];

    function myDirective($http, $timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {

            },
            link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
               //MyCode
        },
            templateUrl: 'js/myDirective/myDirective.html'
        };
    }
```

Now, I want to apply I filter:

```
.filter('filterByProperty', function () {
    /* array is first argument, each additional argument is prefixed by a ":" in filter markup*/
    return function (dataArray, searchTerm, propertyName) {
        if (!dataArray) return;
        /* when term is cleared, return full array*/
        if (!searchTerm) {
            return dataArray
        } else {
            /* otherwise filter the array */
            var term = searchTerm.toLowerCase();
            return dataArray.filter(function (item) {
                return item[propertyName].toLowerCase().indexOf(term) > -1;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

What my problem is that I don't understand where should I put this code.Because wherever I put it, it keep showing error like:- `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token`. Can anyone tell me what is the proper syntax?

Comment: Include directive template, preferably plunker or similar. Just inject $filter in directive and use $filter('filterByProperty')(...)

Comment: getting error `NaNilterByPropertyFilter`